# Как распределить логику между классами UI

Tags: java, android, kotlin, ui

У меня есть класс которые в себе содержит логику `RecyclerView`, также в этом классе содержится логика меню, а помимо этого еще `toolBar` и другие компоненты UI.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли перенести логику меню в отдельный класс, `toolBar` соответственно, а в основном классе `RecyclerViewActivity` объединить их для работы с `R.layout.recyclerview_activity`?

Comment: файл ресурсов `R` виден в любой точке вашего приложения и он не содержит логики, ваш вопрос не совсем понятен...

Comment: @mit,  в файле `R.layout.recyclerview_activity` я описал UI, а в классе `RecyclerViewActivity` я описал логику  виджета `RecyclerView`, `ProgressBar` и.т.д, из-за этого класс `RecyclerViewActivity` стал трудно читабельным, я бы хотел логику распределит между классами.

Comment: это вопрос архитектуры приложения, сейчас гугл продвигает [свою архитектуру](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html), которая сильно напоминает MVP, рекомендую почитать о MVС, MVP, MVVM (не зацикливайтесь на clean arhitecthure - это понятие для полных систем, а мы, аондроид разработчики - это просто frontend)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете, если я правильно понимаю вопрос. 
Необязательно для этого отдельный класс, если вы используете `Kotlin` , можно сделать через [extensions](https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/reference/extensions.html).

Конкретно для вашего примера, кусок кода и реализацию с помощью `extension` можете посмотреть здесь - [репозиторий с кодом на github](https://github.com/elsemTim/android-kotlin-bus_schedule/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/timurmuhortov/dubnabus/extension/Extensions.kt).

update: Я вижу что человек поставил мне `-1` за ответ. Просто если вы хотите вынести логику из вашего Activity(Fragment), то конечно нужно посмотреть в сторону `MVC, MVVM, MVP`. Каждый из них стоит применять в зависимости от задачи, но я бы рекомендовал `MVP`, как по мне он более универсальный.

Вот отличный tutorial, как можно реализовать MVP без библиотек: [ссылка на гайд](http://startandroid.ru/ru/blog/493-mvp-dlja-nachinajuschih-bez-bibliotek-i-interfejsov.html).

Comment: Я у вашем проекте увидел Dagger 2. Я только сегодня начал его изучать, там вроде как писали мне выше можно распределить зависимости. extensions это подобие Dagger?

Comment: @CegreiUlanov неее, extension это методы расширения, грубо говоря статические методы которые позволяют вам добавить функционал в ваш класс, при этом не меня реализацию самого класса. А dagger это IOC контейнер, который реализует принцип - я сам ничего не делаю, за меня это делает другой, но я говорю как

Comment: спасибо за обновленную версию ответа, он мне ответил на мой вопрос. P.S Я вам не ставил минус, видимо  это кто-то другой.